# Prove $|x - y|\le|x| + |y|$ (Spivak's Calculus Book)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was doing this problem and I got stuck so much time, and then I conclude this.

$$|x - y|\le|x| + |y| .$$

Then, square both sides

$$|(x - y)(x - y)|\le(|x| + |y|)².$$

Since $(x - y)²$ is always positive, as well as $x²$ and $y²$, we get

$$(x - y)²\le x² + 2|xy| + y².$$

Develop the product

$$x² -2xy + y² \le x² + 2|xy| + y²$$

$$-2xy\le2|xy|$$

$$-xy\le|xy|$$

And this is true.

I'd like to know if I did this correctly and If there's a smaller/easier proof because the problem is doing by a very short proof.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include `$...$` around mathematical expressions?

Comment: Already fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty of using `$$...$$` to center some mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct; do make sure that every step you have taken can also be taken in reverse. So far you have a proof that
$$\textbf{If}\quad|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|\quad\textbf{then}\quad-xy\leq|xy|,$$
but of course you want to prove the opposite implication.

A shorter proof would be to use the triangle inequality;
$$|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\leq |x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|.$$

Comment: @Servaes All transformations were equivalent due to non-negativity… hence actually it was not just an "if … then" but an "iff"

Comment: That's the point yes.

Comment: @Gono Indeed, but this is not clear from the proof in the question. No mention of nonnegativity is made (or that an equivalence is proved), so it is worth making this explicit.

Comment: Yes… unfortunately not many people care about good notation. So one never knows if just the notation is bad or a if there is something missing. So it's good to note this :)

Comment: What thing I have to improve?

Comment: You have to prove the reverse implication. So check that all your steps are reversible, and explain why they are reversible.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is mostly correct, but you should mention that, for $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$,

> $a\le b$ if and only if $a^2\le b^2$

and that you can apply this because $|x-y|\ge0$ and $|x|+|y|\ge0$. Also you should say that the inequalities you write are equivalent to each other.

In the following steps, each line is equivalent to the one below it; also we use $|a|^2=a^2$ and that adding equal terms to both sides of an inequality doesn't change it.
\begin{align}
& |x-y|\le|x|+|y| \\[4px]
& |x-y|^2\le(|x|+|y|)^2 \\[4px]
& x^2-2xy+y^2\le x^2+2|x|\,|y|+y^2 \\[4px]
& {-}2xy\le |2xy|
\end{align}
Since the last inequality is true (because $-a\le|a|$ for every $a$), we end the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is absolutely correct and I think that your approach is simplest and shortest in the sense that you don't need to appeal to (and prove) any lemma.

In @Servaes's approach, he appeals to this inequality $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$, which certainly needs a proof too.

Bonus: $||x|-|y|| \le |x+y|\le |x|+|y|$.

Comment: Maybe I had to think of that, the first theorem of the book is $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$ Then, I tried doing transitive propertie with $|x - y| \le |x + y|$. But the case when y is less than 0 the inequality isn't true

Comment: @Enigsis This inequality $|x - y| \le |x + y|$ is not true.

Comment: That's why I isn't use it, it isn't true when y is less than 0

Answer (score 0):

You start from what you want to prove and then you square both sides, find something true and conclude.

Using this method I can prove that $$3\leq -6$$
Indeed, square both sides, you find $9\leq 36$ which is true.

What you need to add is that $a\leq b$ is indeed equivalent to $a^2\leq b^2$ whenever $a,b\geq 0$.

That is because

- if $b\geq 0$ then $$a^2\leq b^2\implies \sqrt{a^2}\leq \sqrt{b^2}=b\implies |a|\leq b\implies a\leq b$$
- if $a\geq 0$ then $a\leq b\implies a\cdot a\leq a\cdot b\leq b\cdot b$.

Comment: Yes, but, I square both sides because $|x - y| \ge 0$ and $|x| + |y| \gt 0$

Comment: @Enigsis You should then state it explicitly. A teacher will see such "proofs" all the time, and very seldom by students who would actually be able to fill the gaps. So the only way to show that you are that student is by actually filling the gap. Don't start by what you want to prove, or explain why you can do so.

Comment: I didn't do that because, |x| be always a positive number and I think that you don't have to explain that

Comment: @Enigsis What you have to explain is not that $|x|$ is a non-negative number. It's the fact that when $a,b$ are non-negative, $a\leq b$ is **equivalent** to $a^2\leq b^2$. If you don't do that (and if you're a student), you will not get full marks, unless your teacher is lazy as well.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier “whenever $a\ge0$”. Otherwise you're saying that $-3\le 1$ implies $(-3)^2\le 1^2$.

Comment: Thank you for that, as a mathematician is a good practice?

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I forgot the other half.

Comment: @Enigsis Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

That's right to me. Also you can use the classical triangle inequality $$|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\le|x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|$$